# Several Series with the same xAxis data in HighChart

Tags: datetime, highcharts, time-series

I'm using Highchart to plot multiple series (about 20) on two yAxes and a single datetime xAxis. The data is dynamically loaded via a PHP script that provides a JSON answer. So far, so good.

My issue is that in order to by Highchart compliant, I have to send the datetime information for each series via the network (Sure, I could alter the JSON data in JS after having received the datetime information only once, but that's also a hassle). 500 data points times 20 series times 13 bytes for a timestamp = 130KB of traffic for each refresh, when 1/20 of that would be sufficient.

My question is: Is there a possibility to pass a "series" (the datetime) information to the xAxis and then assign the yAxes-series by order of occurance to the xAxis value? I.e. I pass:

[1361796390000,1361796400000,1361796410000] to the xAxis, and
[1,2,3] to the yAxis

and Highchart assigns 1 to 1361796390000, 2 to 1361796400000 and so forth?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need to pass the datetime for each data point in your series.  You only need to pass the start datetime of the series and then use pointStart to let the chart know when to start counting, like so:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Wind Speed',
    data: [0.52, 0.778, 0.746, 0.594, 0.716, 0.793, 0.648, 0.828, 0.202, 0.066, 0.116, 0.116, 0.17, 0.195, 0.051, 0, 0.368, 2.365, 2.841, 2.693, 2.416, 2.541, 2.429, 2.888],
    pointStart: 1360893600000,
    pointInterval: 3600000
}]
```

See in action at: http://jsfiddle.net/Reality_Extractor/pNFYL/

pointStart expects [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) though there are many different ways how you could easily come up with the particular time you need.  I just hardcoded it in the example for demonstration purposes.

When you use pointStart then pointInterval is necessary to accurately assign time to the datapoints.  It's worth noting that this only works with data which has regular pointIntervals.  If you have irregular data you do need to supply a datetime for each datapoint.

This doesn't quite answer your question about passing the time as an array and then assigning it to the xAxis, but I do believe that the pointStart approach is less complex than array assignments.

Also, somewhat related, depending on how often your data updates you should be caching it on the server, and also the client, to prevent unnecessary refreshes over the network if the data didn't actually change.

Comment: Thank you so much for your post, which does answer my question. The issue is that I _usually_ have regular pointintervals (every 10 seconds). However, it might happen that every now and again, a data set is not available. I could still pass those missing values as NULL-values to HighCharts - that is what I'll try.

Comment: This only works if all of the data is separated exactly the same amount and there are no missing data points in a given time span.